# I forgot to select option of 'Copy items into destination group’s folder' while adding files from a different project

Tags: xcode

I copied files from an old Xcode project and used it in my current one. I made a lot of changes in my current project, including in the files copied from the old project. Now I can't run them on another computer without including the old project.

Is there any way I can separate them now ? 
I don't want to delete the files and add it again in the project.

Comment: Have you tried just copying the files into you project folder in the filesystem?

Comment: Side note - Why are you using Xcode 4.3? That's a bit old to be doing iOS development. You need to be using Xcode 4.6 if you plan to submit to the app store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save a copy of the files in their current state. Then remove the references to the files in the new project. Now add the copies you saved off (and choose to copy them). Once done you can delete the copies you made earlier.

But keep in mind that this leaves the files from the original project with all of the changes you have made. Unless you have made proper use of source code control of you have backups, there is no way to revert the files in the old project back to their proper state.